Wie schreibt man trennbare Verben in Imperativsätzen?
I know that the separable prefix is put at the end of an Imperative sentence. But I saw this variant

Macht mit bei unserer Umfrage.

Is this correct? Can we use the prefix right after the verb?

Keep in mind that the title should ask the question you actually want to ask, which is why doesn't 'mit' come at the end of this particular sentence. You put the answer to the question in the title as the first sentence in the body of the question, and it's been answered here as well. Don't assume everyone will read past the title before voting to close the question as a duplicate. PS. It's also helpful to keep the question title and body in the same language. That can be whatever language you're most comfortable with.

The former prefix of separable verbs must always stand at the end of the clause.
Examples with the verb: abwaschen
Indikativ, Futur I (not separated):

Sebastian wird das Geschirr, das während der ganzen Woche verwendet worden war, erst am Samstag abwaschen.

Indikativ, Präsens (separated):

Sebastian wäscht das Geschirr, das während der ganzen Woche verwendet worden war, erst am Samstag ab.

Imperativ:

Sebastian, bitte wasche das Geschirr, das während der ganzen Woche verwendet worden war, am Samstag ab.

But:
There is something that is called Nachfeld. This is a position in German sentences, that normally is left empty, i.e. it normally doesn't exist. The Nachfeld (literally: after-field) is an optional position after the "last" position, which then no longer really is the last position.
The Nachfeld can be used in sentences, where verbs exist in the "last" position, but when the distance between position 2 and the last position is so big, that it becomes difficult to understand the sentence. Sometimes it is also used for stylistic reasons.
Without Nachfeld (standard word order) (verb = mitmachen = participate)

Macht bei unserer Umfrage mit.

Using the Nachfeld:

Macht mit bei unserer Umfrage.

So, technically, the particle mit still is standing at the "last" position of the sentence, but also the Nachfeld after this "last" position is used.
More important: It stands right after the main part of the verb just by accident. If there was more content in the sentence, it still can't be placed right after the verb:
Correct: Standard word order:

Macht bitte alle bei unserer Umfrage mit.

Also Correct: "bei unserer Umfrage" in the Nachfeld:

Macht bitte alle mit bei unserer Umfrage.

Wrong: Separated particle right after the main part of the verb.

Macht mit bitte alle bei unserer Umfrage.


I find this answer fantastic, thanks Hubert! Great idea to have started with the "normal" rules, only then introducing the Nachfeld.
